# Table API to join two Kafka streams simultaneously

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

I have a Kafka producer that reads data from two large files and sends them in the JSON format with the same structure:

`def create_sample_json(row_id, data_file): return {'row_id':int(row_id), 'row_data': data_file}`

The producer breaks every file into small chunks and creates JSON format from each chunk and sends them in a for-loop finally.

The process of sending those two files happens simultaneously through multithreading.

I want to do **join** from those streams (**s1.row_id == s2.row_id**) and eventually some stream processing while my producer is sending data on Kafka. Because the producer generates a huge amount of data from multiple sources, I can't wait to consume them all, and it must be done simultaneously.

I am not sure if Table API is a good approach but this is my pyflink code so far:

```
from pyflink.datastream.stream_execution_environment import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import  EnvironmentSettings
from pyflink.table.expressions import col
from pyflink.table.table_environment import StreamTableEnvironment

KAFKA_SERVERS = 'localhost:9092'

def log_processing():
  env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
  env.add_jars("file:///flink_jar/kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar")
  env.add_jars("file:///flink_jar/flink-connector-kafka-1.16.1.jar")
  env.add_jars("file:///flink_jar/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.16.1.jar")

  settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance() \
    .in_streaming_mode() \
    .build()

  t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env, environment_settings=settings)

  t1 = f"""
         CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table1(
            row_id INT,
            row_data STRING
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka',
          'topic' = 'datatopic',
          'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{KAFKA_SERVERS}',
          'properties.group.id' = 'MY_GRP',
          'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
          'format' = 'json'
        )
        """

 t2 = f"""
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2(
            row_id INT,
            row_data STRING
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka',
          'topic' = 'datatopic',
          'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{KAFKA_SERVERS}',
          'properties.group.id' = 'MY_GRP',
          'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
          'format' = 'json'
        )
        """
 p1 = t_env.execute_sql(t1)
 p2 = t_env.execute_sql(t2)
```

// please tell me what should I do next:

// Questions:

// 1) Do I need to consume data in my consumer class separately, and then insert them into those tables, or data will be consumed from what we implemented here (as I passed the name of the connector, topic, bootstartap.servers, etc...)?

// 2) If so:

2.1) how can I make join from those streams in Python?

2.2) How can I prevent the previous data as my Producer will send thousands of messages? I want to make sure that not to make duplicate queries.

// 3) If not, what should I do?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> // 1) Do I need to consume data in my consumer class separately, and then insert them into those tables, or data will be consumed from what we implemented here (as I passed the name of the connector, topic, bootstartap.servers, etc...)?

The later one, data will be consumed by the 'kafka' table connector which we implemented. And you need to define a Sink table as the target you insert, the sink table could a kafka connector table with a topic that you want to ouput.

> 2.1) how can I make join from those streams in Python?

You can write SQL to join table1 and table2 and then insert into your sink table in Python

> 2.2) How can I prevent the previous data as my Producer will send thousands of messages? I want to make sure that not to make duplicate queries.

You can filter these messages before 'join' or before 'insert', a 'WHERE' clause is enough in your case